# Console Application-Asp.net-using one class in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created class1.cs in my project
that contains `public int a;`

in the same project I have another program with namespace basic and class name program
in that program class also contains main method.
In the main method if i am trying to create object for class1 i am getting error
class1 is not present in the current context or missing assembly reference.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create instace of class by including namesapce of added assembly like

```
namespace.class1 c1 = new namesapce.class1();
```

or include namespace above like

```
using namespace;

   class1 c1= new class1();
```

here namespace is get replace by the name of namespace in which contains class1 in it.

Comment: [Visual Studio smart tag](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/08/09/one-of-my-favorite-visual-studio-shortcut-very-useful/) can help you setting up the right namespace (shortcut Ctrl+.).